# Binary classification predict() method : sklearn vs keras

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, deep-learning, keras, classification

I try to migrate my **sklearn** code to **keras** on a basic **binary classification** example.
I have question about the **keras** *predict()* method that returns different than **sklearn**.

### sklearn

```
print("X_test:")
print(X_test)
y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
print("y_pred:")
print(y_pred)
```

> XGBClassifier(base_score=0.5, colsample_bylevel=1, colsample_bytree=1,
>          gamma=0, learning_rate=0.1, max_delta_step=0, max_depth=3,
>          min_child_weight=1, missing=None, n_estimators=100, nthread=-1,
>          objective='binary:logistic', reg_alpha=0, reg_lambda=1,
>          scale_pos_weight=1, seed=0, silent=True, subsample=1)

--- Predict Sklearn ---

> X_test: [[   1.      90.      62.    ...,   27.2      0.58    24.   ] 
>   [   7.     181.      84.    ...,   35.9      0.586   51.   ]  [  13.
>   152.      90.    ...,   26.8      0.731   43.   ]  ...,  [   4.     118.      70.    ...,   44.5      0.904   26.   ]  [   7.     152.      88.    ...,   50.       0.337   36.   ]  [   7.     168.      88.    ...,   38.2      0.787   40.   ]]
>
> y_pred: [ 0.  1.  1.  0.  1.  1.  0.  0.  1.  0.  1.  0.  1.  1.  0. 
>   0.  0.  1.
>     0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.
>     0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  1.  0.  ...
>     0.  0.  1.  0.  1.  0.  0.  1.  0.  1.  0.  0.  1.  0.  1.  0.  1.  0.
>     0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.
>     0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  1.  1.  0.  0.  1.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.
>     1.  1.]

Datatype of *predict()* return : a binary vector of *X_test* dimension (OK).

### Keras

```
score = aTSSeqModel.evaluate(X_test, Y_test2, batch_size=32)
```

> Score: [1.4839521383676004, 0.6338582667778796]

What those 2 values represent ?

```
print("--- Predict Keras ---")
print("X_test:")
print(X_test)
Y_pred2 = aTSSeqModel.predict(X_test, batch_size=32)
print("Y_pred:")
print(Y_pred2)
```

> keras.models.Sequential object at 0x7fae3a60b438

--- Predict Keras ---

> X_test: [[   1.      90.      62.    ...,   27.2      0.58    24.   ] 
>   [   7.     181.      84.    ...,   35.9      0.586   51.   ]  [  13.
>   152.      90.    ...,   26.8      0.731   43.   ]  ...,  [   4.     118.      70.    ...,   44.5      0.904   26.   ]  [   7.     152.      88.    ...,   50.       0.337   36.   ]  [   7.     168.      88.    ...,   38.2      0.787   40.   ]]
>
> Y_pred: [[  9.07712865e-21]  [  0.00000000e+00]  [  1.27839347e-25]  [
>   2.38120656e-22]  [  5.51314650e-20]  [  1.99869346e-22]  [  1.54212393e-19]...

Is it the correct way to use *predict()* with **keras** model ?

I would expect a binary vector, as **sklean** does, that is the result of prediction apply to the *X_test* data set.
What represents that 2D vector and its values ?

Thanks for answers.

Comment: You need to include your Keras model to get an answer for both questions.

Answer (score 8):

> What those 2 values represent ?

Assuming you compiled your model with the `metrics` flag set as

```
model.compile(optimizer='...', loss='...', metrics=['acc'])
```

then the call to `model.evaluate(X, Y)` will return an array in which the first value is the loss between `model.predict(X)` and `Y`, and the second value is the accuracy on the same data.
It extends to other metrics, too.

> Is it the correct way to use predict() with keras model?

It is.
Scikit-learn's `predict()` returns an array of shape `(n_samples, )`, whereas Keras' returns an array of shape `(n_samples, 1)`.
The two arrays are equivalent for your purposes, but the one from Keras is a bit more general, as it more easily extends to the multi-dimensional output case.
To convert from the Keras output to Sklearn's, simply call `y_pred.reshape(-1)`.
As to why the values from Scikit-learn get rounded automatically, I have no idea, but it might have to do with the internal datatypes used by Sklearn. If you wish, you can round the values from Keras like this:

```
y_pred[y_pred <= 0.5] = 0.
y_pred[y_pred > 0.5] = 1.
```

Cheers